# angular property binding with an array

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to assign an array to a property and then transform it to a string. it will be the class of the component.

```
btnClasses="[{'btn'},{'btn-outline-primary'},{'text-capitalize mx-1'}]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Why should you do that? If you're trying to assign classes to the button from code, you should simply append them to a string and then assign it to the tag attr.class in html side.

TS:

```
// btnClass is a class property
btnClass = 'btn btn-outline-primary text-capitalize mx-1';
if (isBtnEnabled) {
    btnClass += ' enabled';
}
```

HTML:

```
<button [attr.class]="btnClass">Test</button>
```

Comment: i need to pass an array to a property l

Comment: What is your goal with it? Could you give more details about the task?